# Dynamic inline telegram keyboard in python

Tags: python, telegram

How do I create a keyboard from a list? The list is formed from an SQL query. For example

```
list_of_animals = ['cat','dog','mouse']
```

Below is an example of a static keyboard.

```
kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
kb_dog = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Собаку', callback_data='dog')
kb_cat = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Кошку', callback_data='cat')
kb_mouse = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Мышь', callback_data='mouse')
kb.add(kb_dog, kb_cat, kb_mouse)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет', reply_markup=kb)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)
async def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'dog':
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Собаку так собаку')

    elif call.data == 'cat':
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Котиков все любят')

    elif call.data == 'mouse':
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Серьёзно, мышь?')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some_strings = ["col1", "col2", "row2"]
button_list = [[KeyboardButton(s)] for s in some_strings]
```

check [this](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#build-a-menu-with-buttons) for more snippets.